# DOM order matters for accessibility in web components with RTL/LTR options?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, arabic, web-component, wcag2.0

I'm trying to make react components with accessibility at least AA level according to [WCAG](https://www.wuhcag.com/wcag-checklist), In other hands, My components need to have RTL (right to left) and LTR (left to right) option, LTR is my default configuration and everything is according to AA rules but when I change to RTL version all my visual is updated but the DOM order is the same.
In this article [DOM order Matter](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/dom-order-matters) it's clear the DOM order matter then I ask:

- It's my component accessible?
- How should I make my component to be 100% accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DOM order is correct and the tabbing order and reading order (when using a screen reader) is correct, then when it switches to RTL, you shouldn't have to do anything.  The browser should handle tabbing the DOM in RTL order.

Comment: Thank you, And yes I've my DOM in a correct order and when I change to RTL the screen reader and tabbing order works fine even on windows, but when I inspect the page code with Devtool-console I see my DOM doesn't change the order.

Comment: your DOM will not be affected when you switch from LTR to RTL.  your code doesn't change.  the browser handles navigating the DOM in RTL order.